# Capacitor selection - effect of reducing size of the MLCC capacitor in an audio application

Tags: capacitor, decoupling-capacitor, component-selection

We are developing an audio application using the TI TLV320AIC3111 codec and we are referring to the [EVM document](https://www.ti.com/tool/TLV320AIC3111EVM-K) for the same. On this document, they've used a couple of 47uF 1210 capacitors (pg 23). However, we have a space constraint and are looking to find a smaller package for them.

What parameters do we need to look at before choosing a smaller package? How will the ESR be affected by taking a smaller package?

Comment: You start by understanding the critical performance requirements for those devices in the target design. Then decide if a smaller capacitor (with somewhat weaker critical performances in some key areas) will work in the target design with acceptable degradation in some parameter or other. You **don't start** by guessing what the critical factors might be and then looking in a data sheet because, that is the wrong way round - analyse the requirements from the circuit.

Comment: I only see one 1206 cap on the BOM, C3.  It's a 10uF 16V cap.  It looks like decoupling on a 5V supply.  If you go with a smaller cap the DC derating will be worse and you will wind up with a smaller effective capacitance there.  ESR is probably somewhat worse, but for bulk decoupling it probably doesn't matter.  I'd guess for that one cap a smaller package would probably work, but I didn't do enough homework to say for sure.

Comment: @JohnD I'm sorry I meant to refer to 1210 package but inadvertently ended up writing 1206. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several 47µF caps on the schematics:

- Power supply decoupling (C15 C16)

Capacitance of Class 2 ceramic dielectrics decreases with increasing electric field, and the field is proportional to voltage/thickness. You can use a better dielectric (X7R) that holds its capacitance better for example. You have to **determine how much capacitance you actually need, and then choose what caps you will use to get that capacitance at the actual voltage you use**. If you want accurate capacitance vs voltage graphs you can try [murata simsurfing](https://ds.murata.co.jp/simsurfing/mlcc.html?lcid=en-us#) to plot curves and compare various caps (check "capacitance vs DC bias" in the menu), here is an example:

[image]

- Headphone output DC blocking cap (C19 C20)

Since MLCC capacitance varies with bias voltage, when used in any kind of filter they will introduce harmonic distortion, sometimes in very "generous" amounts especially at low frequencies. **Depending on your requirements, if you want low distortion, you may have to replace the output caps with tantalums**. This is why headphone amps chips which do not require output caps are being offered.

Regarding your question, lowering the cap value to use a smaller one would also change the bass cutoff frequency depending on headphone impedance. So you have to account for this.

- Mic Bias filter cap (C14)

MLCC is piezoelectric and microphonic, so using it for mic bias could be trouble... although if the microphone is on the same board, it will pick up the board vibrations anyway so perhaps it wouldn't be a problem. To reduce capacitor value, it would be simpler to use a higher value resistor in the RC filter.

Comment: What if I choose to keep the values for the C19 and C20 Caps the same and decide to take a smaller size? What kind of effects might I see on the audio? @peufeu

Comment: Smaller size means higher capacitance variation with voltage across the cap, so higher distortion on bass frequency on the headphone output when used with low impedance headphones (32 ohms). This is only a problem if this is a hi-fi product. Otherwise, with cheap earbuds, adding distortion at low frequencies may actually sound better ! (ie, it sounds like there is more bass)... You can try it.

Comment: Also, with 32 ohms headphones, a 47µF capacitor value will make a high pass filter around 100 Hz so if you want good bass on the headphone output, a larger cap value would help. That depends on the intended use of the product, if it is intended for speech, extra bass or a bit more distortion don't matter.

Comment: Okay, I see. Our microphone will be in a different enclosure from the actual PCB but the sounds we shall be measuring are very low in amplitude and susceptible to noise. How big of a factor will microphonics by MLCC play @peufeu

Comment: That's impossible to say, it depends on how much vibration/flexing there is on your board (due to the loudspeakers for example).

Comment: Okay. Also if I choose tantalum caps on c19 and c20, will the higher esr affect the output?  Would c0g caps be a good option?@peufeu

Comment: C0G caps are not available in µF values. Tantalum is generally recommended as headphone coupling cap as it has low distortion compared to ceramic. A few ohms ESR is negligible even with lowest headphone impedance of 32 ohms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102190/discussion-between-souvik-saha-and-peufeu).